# The correct way of compute indicator function in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, piecewise

$$X_1= \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]} $$
$$X_2= \mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}, X_3= \mathbb{1}_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}, $$
$$X_4= \mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{3}]},  X_5= \mathbb{1}_{[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]},  X_6= \mathbb{1}_{[\frac{2}{3},1]}, $$

I need plot this function, what is the correct way to compute this result from Mathematica?

```
Plot[{1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

I have simple function, but I don't know how plot of $X_2= \mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$ for interval $[0,1]$. Also I am interesting about representing of few function on the same image.

Comment: You might use `UnitStep` or `SquareWave`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
k = 4;
xx = BlockMap[Boole[# <= t <= #2] & @@ # &, #, 2, 1] & /@ Subdivide /@ Range[k];

Column[Plot[#, {t, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> 1 -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1/5, PlotTheme -> "Minimal"] & /@ xx]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

kglr gives the general solution using Iverson brackets (`Boole[]` in *Mathematica*), which are entirely equivalent to the indicator function. Alternatively, one could also use the `UnitBox[]` function. Using kglr's example:

```
With[{m = 6}, 
     Column[Plot[#, {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/5, Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True,
                 ImageSize -> 1 -> 300, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal"] & /@ 
            Table[UnitBox[k t - j - 1/2], {k, m}, {j, 0, k - 1}]]]
```

[image: indicator functions]

Another function equivalent to `UnitBox[k t - j - 1/2]` is `BSplineBasis[0, 0, k t - j]`.